# Why doesn't the adjacent sibling selector work?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

According to the definition of adjacent sibling selector the following code should work. However it does not. I don't seem to find any mistake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#p2+h4{
    color:red;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>
        <p id="p2">This is the sibling of the selected para</p>
        <p>
            <h4>this should not be colored</h4>
        </p>
        <h4>this should be colored</h4>
    </p>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't nest paragraphs tags. You also can't have heading tags in paragraph tags.

Comment: "According to the definition of adjacent sibling selector" You seem to have misunderstood the definition, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is invalid. `p` element permitted content is [phrasing content](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/terminology.html#phrasing-content). Additional css adjacent sibling selector selects following the rule:

> Adjacent sibling selectors have the following syntax: E1 + E2, where
>   E2 is the subject of the selector. The selector matches if E1 and E2
>   share the same parent in the document tree and E1 immediately precedes
>   E2, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments).

in your example element with id `#p2` is not immediately precedes `h4`. You can fix your html and use general sibling selector:

```css
#p2 ~ h4 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="p2">This is the sibling of the selected para</p>
  <div>
    <h4>this should not be colored</h4>
  </div>
  <h4>this should be colored</h4>
</div>
```

This will work because general sibling selector selects according to the following rule:

> The following-sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~)
>   character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The
>   elements represented by the two sequences share the same parent in the
>   document tree and the element represented by the first sequence
>   precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the
>   second one.

here element with id `#p2` shares the same parent with second element `h4` in html but not with the first.

Take a look also [Difference between the selectors div + p (plus) and div ~ p (tilde)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282375/difference-between-the-selectors-div-p-plus-and-div-p-tilde/26282459#26282459)

**References:**

[Adjacent sibling selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

[Following-sibling combinator](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#general-sibling-combinators)

Comment: Explain the downvote please.

Comment: This colors both `h4`s which does not match what the OP intended. I have no idea why the OP accepted your answer. It couldn't have solved their problem - unless, of course, they mistated their problem in the first place, which is why I have chosen to downvote the question instead of your answer (the downvote on your answer is not mine, but I can see why someone else might have downvoted it).

Comment: @BoltClock It could in this case because browsers auto-un-nest p tags, so it seemed to work as desired in this specific case

Comment: @Zach Saucier: I'm closing the question since the asker never bothered to follow up.

Answer (score 7):

`H4` is not **immediately preceded** by the `#p2`. You should use a more loose sibling selector `~` (general sibling combinator):

```
#p2 ~ h4
```

### [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

- `E + F`   an F element **immediately** preceded by an E element
- `E ~ F`   an F element preceded by an E element

### Important

But as many others have suggested in comments (and invalidly in answers) your HTML isn't valid. You can't just nest elements that shouldn't be nested. Browsers will *reformat* it conforming to [the specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content). Paragraph element can only contain phrasing content.

> Elements belonging to phrasing category are `<abbr>`, `<audio>`, `<b>`, `<bdo>`, `<br>`, `<button>`, `<canvas>`, `<cite>`, `<code>`, `<command>`, `<datalist>`, `<dfn>`, `<em>`, `<embed>`, `<i>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input>`, `<kbd>`, `<keygen>`, `<label>`, `<mark>`, `<math>`, `<meter>`, `<noscript>`, `<object>`, `<output>`, `<progress>`, `<q>`, `<ruby>`, `<samp>`, `<script>`, `<select>`, `<small>`, `<span>`, `<strong>`, `<sub>`, `<sup>`, `<svg>`, `<textarea>`, `<time>`, `<var>`, `<video>`, `<wbr>` and **plain text** (not only consisting of white spaces characters).
>
> A few other elements belong to this category, but only if a specific condition is fulfilled:
>
> - `<a>`, if it contains only phrasing content
> - `<area>`, if it is a descendant of a  element
> - `<del>`, if it contains only phrasing content
> - `<ins>`, if it contains only phrasing content
> - `<link>`, if the itemprop attribute is present
> - `<map>`, if it contains only phrasing content
> - `<meta>`, if the itemprop attribute is present

Based on reformatted HTML by the browsers, both headings will get colored as they both become siblings to the `#p2` paragraph and are both preceded by the same paragraph.

Comment: thanks and btw i am new at this. How will I know which elements or tags can be nested and which can't?

Comment: @raiyan106: I've edited my answer to include the link and excerpt from the specification. Always consult the spec when in doubt. But the quick way of seeing invalid HTML is when it doesn't display correctly and brwser's developer tools show a different DOM tree than you've written (as in this case).

Comment: "more loose" and "adjacent" contradict each other - you probably meant "sibling" and not "adjacent".

Answer (score 0):

Because `p2` isn't adjacent to any `h4`s

This would work

```
<p>stuff</p>
<h4>stuff</h4>
```

But this wouldn't

```
<p>stuff</p>
<anyothertag>
    <h4>stuff</h4>
</anyothertag>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. `<p>` elements cannot contain other `<p>` elements, nor heading elements. If you inspect the code in the page, the browser corrects for it and generates it as:

```
<p></p>
<p id="p2">This is the sibling of the selected para</p>
<p></p>
<h4>this should not be colored</h4>
<p></p>
<h4>this should be colored</h4>
<p></p>
```

Which is why your CSS fails since `#p2+h4` looks for an `<h4>` as the immediate sibling of an element with the ID of p2. You can use either `#p2~h4` or `#p2+p+h4` to select the heading. Note however that `#p2~h4` would also select the second heading.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as browser don't accept nested p tags anyway. Replacing all your p tags with divs would make it work, but that doesn't do it either because you are looking for any elements with the id p2 and is followed immediately by an element of the type h4. Only if you enter something as general as p + h4 you will only address every h4 preceded by a p element. Here's how to make it all work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#p2 + div + h4{
    color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="p2">This is the sibling of the selected para</div>
        <div>
            <h4>this should not be colored</h4>
        </div>
        <h4>this should be colored</h4>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```