# Difference between the selectors div + p (plus) and div ~ p (tilde)

Tags: css, css-selectors

The way that [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) phrases it, they sound the same.

> **[W3Schools' CSS reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**
>
> `div + p`
>   Selects all `<p>` elements that are placed immediately after `<div>` elements
>
> `div ~ p`
>   Selects every `<p>` element that are preceded by a `<div>` element

If a `<p>` element is immediately after a `<div>` element, doesn't that mean that the `<p>` element is preceded by a `<div>` element?

Anyhow, I'm looking for a selector where I can select an element that is place immediately **before** a given element.

Comment: you cannot do `before`. impossible. only with javascript. you'll have to look for it and it all the `before` ones a class to target in your CSS.

Comment: See [this](http://techbrij.com/css-selector-adjacent-child-sibling) for a visual explanation

Answer (score 139, accepted):

**Adjacent sibling selectors X + Y**

> Adjacent sibling selectors have the following syntax: E1 + E2, where
>   E2 is the subject of the selector. The selector matches if E1 and E2
>   share the same parent in the document tree and E1 immediately precedes
>   E2, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments).

```
ul + p {
   color: red;
}
```

> In this example it will select only the
>   element that is immediately preceded by the former element. In this
>   case, only the first paragraph after each ul will have red text.

```css
ul + p {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
        <li>List Item</li>
    </ul>
    <p>This will be red</p>
    <p>This will be black</p>
    <p>This will be black</p>
</div>
```

**General sibling selectors X ~ Y**

> The ~ combinator separates two selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is preceded by the first, and both share a common
>   parent.

```
ul ~ p {
   color: red;
}
```

> This sibling combinator is similar to X + Y, however, it's less
>   strict. While an adjacent selector (ul + p) will only select the first
>   element that is immediately preceded by the former selector, this one
>   is more generalized. It will select, referring to our example above,
>   any p elements, as long as they follow a ul.

```css
ul ~ p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>List Item
      <ul>
        <li>Child</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
  </ul>
  <p>This will be red.</p>
  <p>This will be red.</p>
  <p>This will be red.</p>
  <p>This will be red.</p>
</div>
```

**Source**

[code.tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

[General sibling selectors MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

[Adjacent sibling selectors w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)

Comment: This answer is nothing more than a quotation of another article, with no attempt to address the specific question at hand. The examples given don't do a very good job of addressing the question either.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks i get your point. I always welcome feedback from you. But i think my answer explain to OP what is the difference between those selectors.

Comment: That's true. Although it doesn't quite address the question, it does a reasonable job of illustrating the difference between the two selectors.

Answer (score 34):

> If a `<p>` element is immediately after a `<div>` element, doesn't that mean that the `<p>` element is preceded by a `<div>` element?

This is correct. In other words, `div + p` is a *proper subset* of `div ~ p` — anything matched by the former is *also* matched by the latter, by necessity.

The difference between `+` and `~` is that `~` matches all following siblings regardless of their proximity from the first element, as long as they both share the same parent.

Both of these points are most succinctly illustrated with a single example, where each rule applies a different property. Notice that the one `p` that immediately follows the `div` has both rules applied:

```css
div + p {
    color: red;
}

div ~ p {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>Div</div>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
</section>
<section>
    No div
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
</section>
```

> Anyhow, I'm looking for a selector where I can select an element that is place immediately **before** a given element.

Unfortunately, [there isn't one yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector).

Comment: @user4055428 "~ matches all following siblings regardless of their proximity from the first element" 

This explains the real difference, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

consider this example:

```css
p + p { /* the first p immediately after a preceding p */
   color: red; 
} 

p ~ p { /* all p's after a preceding p */
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>1</p>
 <div>separator</div>
    <p>2</p> <!-- only ~ is applied here -->
   <p>3</p> <!-- both + and ~ are applied here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) Adjacent Sibling Selectors (S1 + S2)**

Adjacent sibling selector is used to select a specified element which is immediate next to another specified element. Both elements should be in the same level.

```
div + p {
    color:red;
}
```

[Adjacent Sibling Selectors example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M80O.png)

**2) General Sibling Selectors (S1 ~ S2)**

General sibling selector is used to select all specified sibling elements of another specified element.

```
div ~ p {
   color:red;
}
```

[General Sibling Selectors example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z86jx.png)

**Adjacent Sibling(S1 + S2) vs General Sibling(S1 ~ S2) selectors:**

Adjacent sibling(S1 + S2) selector selects immediate sibling element only but general sibling(S1 ~ S2) selector selects all sibling elements of another specified element. Both cases, both elements(S1 and S2) should be in the same level.

Remaining selectors are explained here:
https://www.csssolid.com/35-css-selectors-to-remember.html

Answer (score 0):

Both `+` and `~` are CSS sibling selectors. But used for two different purposes. See how the color changes in the next sibling/ siblings in both scenarios. For both scenarios, I used different selectors. But you can use any selector to play with this.

1. Adjacent Sibling Selector / `+` - Will apply styles to only the next sibling of the first selector.

```css
#as-h2+#as-p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="as-h2">Adjacent Sibling Example</h2>
<p id="as-p">I'm the adjacent sibling</p>
<p id="as-p">I'm distance from heading</p>
```

2. General Sibling Selector / `~` - Will apply styles to all the siblings who come after the first selector.

```css
.gs-h2~.gs-p {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="gs-h2">General Sibling Example</h2>
<p class="gs-p">I'm the general sibling</p>
<p class="gs-p">I'm general sibling distance from heading 2</p>
```