# Selecting one of the <br> elements in a pair by pure CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a way to select one element, immediately following (or preceding) other by pure CSS?

Foe example, hide one of `<br>` in a `<br><br>` pair:

```
<p>text text <br><br>text text <br>text text <br><br>text text</p>
<p>text text <br>text text <br><br>text text <br><br>text text</p>
<p>text text <br><br>text text <br>text text <br><br>text text</p>
```

and get it prosessed in the end as:

```
<p>text text <br>text text <br>text text <br>text text</p>
<p>text text <br>text text <br>text text <br>text text</p>
<p>text text <br>text text <br>text text <br>text text</p>
```

`display: none;` appled for `br + br` or `br ~ br` don't work as described above.

Comment: br + br {display:none}, see adjacent selector

Comment: [Adjacent selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)

Comment: css cannot remove elements only style them (e.g hide or show them)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that the only thing separating your `br` elements is text. Sibling combinators in CSS ignore all non-element nodes between elements including (but not limited to) comments, text and whitespace, so as far as CSS is concerned, all of your paragraphs have exactly five consecutive `br` children each:

```
<p>  <br><br>  <br>  <br><br>  </p>
<p>  <br>  <br><br>  <br><br>  </p>
<p>  <br><br>  <br>  <br><br>  </p>
```

That is, every `br` after the first in each paragraph is a `br + br` (and by extension [also a `br ~ br`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282375/difference-between-the-selectors-div-p-plus-and-div-p-tilde/28740397#28740397)).

You will need to use JavaScript to iterate the paragraphs, find `br` element nodes that are immediately followed or preceded by another `br` element node rather than a text node, and remove said other node.

```js
var p = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  var node = p[i].firstChild;

  while (node) {
    if (node.nodeName == 'BR' && node.nextSibling.nodeName == 'BR')
      p[i].removeChild(node.nextSibling);

    node = node.nextSibling;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>text text <br><br>text text <br>text text <br><br>text text</p>
<p>text text <br>text text <br><br>text text <br><br>text text</p>
<p>text text <br><br>text text <br>text text <br><br>text text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably unreliable, but works, at least on Firefox:

```css
br {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
br {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>text text <br><br>text text <br>text text <br><br>text text</p>
<p>text text <br>text text <br><br>text text <br><br>text text</p>
<p>text text <br><br>text text <br>text text <br><br>text text</p>
```

Comment: Yeah, it depends entirely on how the browser chooses to implement the br element - there is no consensus there. In fact, this works only on Firefox.