# What is a good way to display only one line break with multiple <br> tags?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML with multiple `<br>` tags:

```
Text<br>
<br>
More text...
```

Using CSS, how to display only one line break with two or more `<br>` tags?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't remove the excess <br> tags?

Comment: Yes, I am not creating it. It comes from an API call.

Comment: @BSeven why not remove them from the API response before rendering?

Comment: @EdCottrell - Because this is a display issue. It seems more elegant to use CSS than changing around the HTML.

Answer (score 4):

I believe

```
br + br {
    display: none;
}
```

should do the job. Essentially that doesn't display any line break that comes directly after another lie break, thereby only displaying the first.

**EDIT**: Only do this if you can be sure all the excessive line breaks you want to hide will be in a different node than the next one you want to show. **YOU PROBABLY DON'T WANT TO DO THIS.**

Comment: Wow, I never thought of this, but it works great

Comment: [This will fail](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30488569/1529630). All `<br>` after the first one (not necessarily consecutively) will be affected.

Comment: @Oriol I totally forgot about that :/ *headdesk* I feel better because I didn't get any reputation from it at least...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
br + br {
    display: none;
}
```