# Hide menu when check is checked

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a toggle for mobile menu, but the `:checked` selector doesn't seem to be working.

**Here is the Code:**

```css
#toggleMenuToggle:checked .nav-css {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="desktop-hidden menuToggle" for="toggleMenuToggle">MENU</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="toggleMenuToggle" id="toggleMenuToggle">
<ul id="dropdown-nav" class="nav-css">
  <li class="n1 current">
    <a class="n1">Test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Shouldn't the `<ul>` have it's display set to none when my checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following solution:

```css
#toggleMenuToggle:checked ~ .nav-css {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="desktop-hidden menuToggle" for="toggleMenuToggle">MENU</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="toggleMenuToggle" id="toggleMenuToggle">
<ul id="dropdown-nav" class="nav-css">
  <li class="n1 current">
    <a class="n1">Test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Explanation:** With your solution the `.nav-css` element have to be a child of the checkbox (`#toggleMenuToggle`). But in your case the `.nav-css` is the following element of the checkbox, so you have to use the `~`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the `+` or `~` selector. The `+` selector selects the adjacent sibling while the `~` selector selects all sibling elements. In this case it does not actually matter which one you choose.

```
#toggleMenuToggle:checked + .nav-css {
  display: none;
}
```

For a nice explanation of the selectors see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26282459/6430127

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your css is that `.nav-css` is not a child of `#toggleMenuToggle`.

Try the following:

```
#toggleMenuToggle:checked ~ .nav-css {
    display: block
}
```

The `~` Selects every `.nav-css` element that are preceded by a `#toggleMenuToggle` element