# why can i not hover the other p element, and get the same reults?

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
  div{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: none;
  }
  .hei:hover+div{
    display: block;
  }
</style>

<p class="hei">slm</p>
<br>
<p class="hei">hei</p>
<div class=""></div>
```

i gave them the same class, but only of the p elements is working. I checked w3 schools, yet could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is because that `+` selector is only targeting next element, when `~` is targeting all next `div's` in your case. So your CSS will be like something similar to this :`.hei:hover~div`.

Here you can find more information about this behavior. 
[Difference between the selectors div + p (plus) and div ~ p (tilde)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282375/difference-between-the-selectors-div-p-plus-and-div-p-tilde)

```
ul ~ p {
   color: red;
}
```

> This sibling combinator is similar to X + Y, however, it's less
>   strict. While an adjacent selector (ul + p) will only select the first
>   element that is immediately preceded by the former selector, this one
>   is more generalized. It will select, referring to our example above,
>   any p elements, as long as they follow a ul.

The second tip: don't use https://www.w3schools.com/ for learning, it has poor examples and did not really cover all the informations. 
Instead go for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Answer (score 0):

The plus sign `+` in a css selector means for

```
p + div
```

> Selects all `<div>` elements that are placed immediately after `<p>` elements

Try it with `~`

> Selects every element that is a next sibling

```css
  div{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: none;
  }
  .hei:hover~div{
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
<p class="hei">slm</p>
<br>
<p class="hei">hei</p>
<div class=""></div>
```