# Using :has in Tailwind with adjacent sibling selectors

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have the following `CSS`, which works as intended.

```css
[data-type='transfer']:has(+ [data-type^='sale_']) {
  opacity: 0.25;
}
```

It looks at data attributes and will hide elements with `data-type="transfer` if they are adjacent to elements containing data attributes starting with "sale_". For clarity, I reduced the opacity instead of hiding the element, to make things as clear as possible what I'm doing.

Here it is in a quick demo:

```css
[data-type='transfer']:has(+ [data-type^='sale_']) {
  opacity: 0.25;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-type="transfer">a transfer</li>
  <li data-type="sale_buyer">a buyer sale</li>  
  <li data-type="transfer">a transfer</li>
  <li data-type="sale_seller">a seller sale</li>    
</ul>
```

How can I convert the working CSS above into Tailwind code now that `:has` is supported?  I tried something like this, but it's not working:

```js
<li className='has-[[data-type="transfer"] + [data-type^="sale_"]]:hidden'>...</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up asking the creator of Tailwind how to do this and this is the answer he gave me. I was missing that first `+` inside the initial left bracket and this is the best answer.

```js
<ul>
  <li class="has-[+[data-type^='sale\_']]:data-[type='transfer']:opacity-25" data-type="transfer">a transfer</li>
  <li class="has-[+[data-type^='sale\_']]:data-[type='transfer']:opacity-25" data-type="sale_buyer">a buyer sale</li>  
  <li class="has-[+[data-type^='sale\_']]:data-[type='transfer']:opacity-25" data-type="transfer">a transfer</li>
  <li class="has-[+[data-type^='sale\_']]:data-[type='transfer']:opacity-25" data-type="sale_seller">a seller sale</li>    
</ul>
```

[Playground demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/sAih345h3M)

Answer (score 0):

If you can work in reverse, [Tailwind's `peer-`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-sibling-state) would be better suited for this. (I didn't even know you could use `:has` to target siblings; `[data-type='transfer'] + [data-type^='sale_']` would be an equivalent CSS selector.)

**Relevant class string:**

```
opacity-25 peer peer-[[data-type=transfer]]:data-[type^=sale\_]:opacity-100
```

(Why `sale\_` and not `sale_`? Underscores constitute as spaces in Tailwind and ordinarily need escaping, although in this instance omitting it does not change output for whatever reason.)

**Generated CSS:**

```
.opacity-25{
  opacity: 0.25
}

.peer[data-type=transfer] ~ .peer-\[\[data-type\=transfer\]\]\:data-\[type\^\=sale\\_\]\:opacity-100[data-type^=sale_]{
  opacity: 1
}
```

[Tailwind Play demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/VHFlGLag2o)

**Edit 1:** Didn't account for the reversed nature of my reversed answer.

**Edit 2:** [`~` is less strict than `+`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282375/difference-between-the-selectors-div-p-plus-and-div-p-tilde), so this is not a perfect answer. Leaving up for posterity.